# What does 所 in 十目所視 do?

Tags: grammar

What does 所 in 十目所視 do? Is it some kind of grammar here?

This is the definition of 所 from my dicitonary:

> 所 所   suǒ    actually; place; classifier for houses, small buildings,
> institutions etc; that which; particle introducing a relative clause
> or passive; CL:個|个[ge4]

Answer (score 6):

It corresponds to these translations in your dictionary:

> that which; particle introducing a relative clause or passive;

所 can be compared to the conjunction (where/what/when) in a clause.

十目所视 what ten eyes see

目力所及 where vision can reach

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the dictionary

> particle introducing a relative clause or passive

[(object) + subject + **所** + verb] = [(object) is verb **by** subject]

[十目(everyone's eyes)+ **所** + 视(watch)] = [watched **by** everyone's eyes]

Another example (with object):

背脊向天人所食

背脊向天 (things that with its back facing the sky = all non-human creatures) is the object

人 (people) is the subject

- 背脊向天[**人**][**所**]食 = all non-human creatures are for [**people**] [**to**] eat
- [**背脊向天**]人[**所**]食 = [**all non-human creatures**] are eaten [**by**] people

> (你被)**十目**(所)视 = (you are) watched (by) **everyone**

Answer (score 0):

十目所视，十手所指
Everyone knows what you're up to.

原指一个人的一举一动,
Originally means,a person's every gesture, every movement,
大家都看得见,指得出。
everyone can see, everyone knows

Answer (score 0):

In here, 所 means "actually".

十(眾)目所視 - Ten (all) eyes actually seeing.